# OMS Linux Agent Configuration for Custom Logs, specifically for tomcat catalina.out log file

Tags: oms

I wonder if anyone out there configured OMS Linux Agent to send catalina.out logs to Logs Analytics in Azure? I have config file but for some reason its not working , it could be that after tomcat upgrade from 8.5.32 -> 8.5.35 file format changed.

Here is my config which is failing to send info:

```
<source>
  @type sudo_tail
  format none
  tag oms.api.tomcat.rota.out
  path /var/lib/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
  pos_file /var/opt/microsoft/omsagent/state/tomcat.log.rota.out.pos
  read_from_head true
  run_interval 30
</source>
```

the error in omsagent.log I see is:

```
2019-05-20 13:05:31 +0000 [info]: INFO Received paths from sudo tail plugin : /var/lib/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
2019-05-20 13:05:31 +0000 [info]: INFO Following tail of /var/lib/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
2019-05-20 13:05:39 +0000 [warn]: Missing DataType or IPName field in record from tag 'oms.api.tomcat.rota.out'
2019-05-20 13:05:58 +0000 [info]: Sending OMS Heartbeat succeeded at 2019-05-20T13:05:58.645Z
```

Please show me how this config should look like to succesfully send logs to Log Analytics Workspace

Regards